# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Помимо этого, роботы обладают зрением, могут разговаривать – само собой, трескучим голосом, и владеют базовыми навыками общения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Помимо этого, роботы обладают зрением, могут разговаривать – само собой, трескучим голосом, и владеют базовыми навыками общения.*

***Помимо этого*** и ***само собой*** — это вводные сочетания, которые не являются членами предложения и выделяются запятыми (реже — тире).
Если вводные "убрать" из предложения, то оно будет иметь такой вид (с однородными сказуемыми, запятая после "голосом" не нужна):

***Роботы*** (что делают?) ***обладают*** зрением, ***могут разговаривать*** трескучим голосом и ***владеют*** базовыми навыками общения.

Теперь о "само собой": если Вы решили обособить вводное сочетание *тире, то оно должно быть с двух сторон.*
Итак, получаем:
***Помимо этого, роботы обладают зрением, могут разговаривать — само собой — трескучим голосом и владеют базовыми навыками общения.***
Или:
***Помимо этого, роботы обладают зрением, могут разговаривать, само собой, трескучим голосом и владеют базовыми навыками общения.***

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написала так: Помимо этого, роботы обладают зрением, могут разговаривать – само собой, трескучим голосом – и владеют базовыми навыками общения.

У Розенталя есть похожий пример (на месте вставки нет знаков препинания), только без вводного слова: Аннушка молча покинула свою засаду, тихо обошла кругом — её детские ножки едва шумели по густой траве — и вышла из чащи подле самого старика (Т.)

**[§ 26. Вводные и вставные конструкции. Розенталь.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123)**

Наш пример без вводного слова: Помимо этого, роботы обладают зрением, могут разговаривать – трескучим голосом – и владеют базовыми навыками общения.

А потом добавляем вводное слово.

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее логичный вариант:

**Помимо этого, роботы обладают зрением, могут разговаривать — само собой, трескучим голосом — и владеют базовыми навыками общения.**

Здесь "трескучим голосом" - уточнение, усиленное вводными словами "само собой".

Уточняющие члены при подчеркивании смысла выделяются или отделяются тире ([ПАС, § 80](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123))